# Update Ionic/AngularJS tabs parameter once created

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app in which user first select an item then get tabs related to actions available for this item.

In order to keep thing simple (and also because I'm not sure how to do otherwise) I pass the object id in the href of the tab so you have /{object_id}/tab1

The tab menu is created by the following :

```
 .state('check', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/check/:eventId",
    templateUrl: "templates/check_menu.html",
     controller: 'checkMenuCtrl'
  })
```

It works perfectly for the first item, but if I go back to the menu and select another object, the href links of the tab menu are still with the first id.

It looks like the $stateParams.object_id used to populate tabs href is never updated.

```
.controller('checkMenuCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.eventid=$stateParams.eventId;
})
```

Any idea of how I could do that ?
Thank you by advance for your help !!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a Codepen? Is the case of *id* work correct here: `$scope.eventid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like abstract controlers are never updated. 
$stateParams are updated in services (factory) so it's the better solution I found so far !

Comment: Seems I ran into the [same probleem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950917/how-to-use-tabs-in-ionic-with-a-abstract-state-parameter-clear-cache-on-naviga). Would you care to post an example how you fixed this?

Comment: no solution, but I request $stateParams from services each time I need them !